# Adding Sonar to Maven Jenkins Job With Credentials Fails

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to get the SonarQube plug-in to work on the Jenkins. I'm using the [official guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven):

1. Created global credentials on the Jenkins with the secret text from the Sonar server: *Administration -> Configuration -> Encryption*
2. Configured the Jenkins and added our SonarQube server and the authentication from 1.
3. Enabled "Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment" on the job configuration
4. Added `$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN` to the goals of the job

All of this results in the exception:

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project com.qualitype.foundation.build: 
Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
```

What I tried to fix this problem:

- added `sonar.login` and `sonar.password` to the *pom.xml*
- added `sonar.login` and `sonar.password` to the job config's goals
- added `sonar.login` and `sonar.password` to the job config's MAVEN_OPTS
- all of the above with a user token as `sonar.login` (from *Profile -> Security -> Tokens*)
- replaced the secret text of the credentials with the aforementioned token
- all of the above just without the variable (e.g. not `$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN` but a fix value)
- using post build step "SonarQube analysis with Maven"

Neither of these work, all have the same exception. What works is just calling `sonar:sonar` and disabling "Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment", because our *pom.xml* is set up like that. The moment I enable "Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment" again, the build fails.

I had hoped to get the Sonar information displayed on the Jenkins job if I use the official plug-in instead of just calling `sonar:sonar`.

How do I get the Sonar plug-in to work with the Jenkins?

Comment: Please add a screen of `Manage Jenkins → Configure System → SonarQube servers` (don't forget to click `Advanced...` button).

Comment: @agabrys Which information is relevant? There's only the name, server URL and  server authentication token filled in, and I'm not really sure I should company internals here.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your **Maven Configuration** under /configureTools/ you have to add the following to your maven settings.xml which is under /configfiles/:

```
<id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>URL to your Sonar-Server</sonar.host.url>
            <sonar.login>the token you generated on Sonaqrqube</sonar.login>             
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

The Sonartoken you can specify in in Sonar Plugin Settings is normally not taken into account for Maven (as long as you don't specify it via -D parameter `script.sh "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=${script.env.getProperty('BRANCH_NAME')} -Dstyle.color=always -Dsonar.login=$token`).
Overall the way Sonarqube is using a token as a user/password replacement didn't fit our automatic instance setup. So we ended up using REST calls to generate a short lived token per build in our custom Jenkins pipeline library.